# Convert a cell containing a list of words into a column

Tags: excel

```
'Bad','good','beautiful,pretty'
```

I want to convert the above into a row with each string in it.But when I use delimiters ' and ,  and then transpose , beautiful and pretty gets separated.But I wanted them to be in the same row.
Like the following

```
Bad
good
beautiful,pretty
```

Is there a way for this?

Comment: How are you using the delimiters?  Please post your formula.

Comment: Since the list of words is in a single cell,i am changing it to columns by using text to columns in data tab and using quotes and comma as delimiters

Comment: There is no built in method that will automatically do this.  you will need vba or nested formula.  With the nested formula route it will depend on what version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use `Text to columns` you will split the result into separate columns (not rows).  You could then copy/paste special transpose to get them into rows.

The most likely reason for you finding `beautiful,pretty` in separate cells is that you specified the double quote and not the single quote as the text qualifier.

If your version of Excel has the `FILTERXML` function, you can use, with your string in `E1`

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(E1,"'", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.!=',' and string-length()>0]")
```

[image]